# Error when running electron app after building

Tags: angular, electron

When I run my electron app without building it works fine. `electron .`

But after building and installing the app. It gives me an error
`TypeError: Error processing argument at index0, conversion failure from undefined at WebContents.NavigationController.loadURL`

anyone know why? I'm using Angular 5 with electron.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to build the electron app from the build files instead of the source.

Comment: Please explain your answer with additional details. This looks very plain for naïve developers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that I had not configured preload file for proper CCB flow.
Then I configured preload file as well while creating the window and then the error disappeared.